# Rotate on scroll javascript not working when getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, scroll, rotation, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I'm using the following js code to rotate various elements on scroll. It works perfectly fine as long as I getElementById. However, there is one image that I would like to rotate that does not have id. Instead, it has several classes. Naturally, I replace getElementById with getElementsByClassName. The problem is that whenever I do that, the code does not work.

Here is the working code:

```
<img src="url" id="logo">

<script>
var example = document.getElementById("logo");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    example.style.transform = "rotate("+window.pageYOffset/10+"deg)";
});
</script>
```

Here is the non-working code:

```
<img src="url" class="circle">

<script>
var example = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    example.style.transform = "rotate("+window.pageYOffset/10+"deg)";
});
</script>
```

P.S. I do not have access to HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking the documentation you can check that while [`Document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById?retiredLocale=it#select-language) return an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) calls to the [`Document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName?retiredLocale=it) method return an [`HtmlCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) collection. You can then select the first element of the collection if it is the one you are looking for:

```
var example = document.getElementsByClassName("circle")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on that line:

```
var example = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
```

The function named `getElementsByClassName` return an array, can be a element but in array, not like does for example `getElementById` passes directly the element, in that case, i assume, the circle class is the first element you want to get, do the next:

```
var example = document.getElementsByClassName("circle")[0];
```

More info of that function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Thank you so much. Am I able to mark both answers as "solved"? If not, I marked the other person's answer simply because he was first. But I still appreciate your answer. Thank you.